# SQLite EXISTS parameter return -1 regardless if the record exists or not, C#

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

I'm having an issue with my SQLite code. I'm trying to check if a record exists in my SQLite table, but for some reason, it always returns -1, no matter if the record exists or not. As much as I understand, it should return 1 if the record exists, and 0 if it doesn't.
Can someone please point me to my error? Thanks!

```
var freeHours = new List<DateTime>();

            User user = new User();

            for (int i = user.HoursOfWork[0]; i < user.HoursOfWork[1]; i++)
            {
                DateTime hour = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, i, 0, 0);
                int exist;

                using (var con = new SQLiteConnection(cs))
                using (var comm = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Schedule WHERE date = @date)", con))
                {
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", hour.ToString());
                    con.Open();

                    exist = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                if(exist != 1) //The object doesn't exists in the DB
                {
                    freeHours.Add(hour);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ExecuteNonQuery should not be used when you expect some data to return. Being it a full set of rows or just a single scalar value.

ExecuteNonQuery will always return -1 when used with a SELECT statement. At least this is [what Microsoft says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) for its implementation, not sure if this is the same with SQLite.

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
> number of rows affected by the command. For all other types of
> statements, the return value is -1.

In your context, when you expect a single SCALAR value then you use ExecuteScalar

```
 exist = (int)comm.ExecuteScalar();
```

The cast is necessary because ExecuteScalar returns an *object*

Comment: It works now! Thank you so much, I really appreciate it :)